# ¿Como saber con Apache POI y java si una columna en excel esta oculta?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hola estoy importando archivos excel con extensión xls y xlsx pero mi duda es como poder detectar si la columna de una celda esta visible u oculta, de antemano gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Ricardo. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! No me resulta clara tu pregunta. ¿La pregunta es "cómo ***detecta***" o "cómo ***se podría detectar***"? Ayudaría además ver el código que tenés hasta ahora para contextualizar y poder contestarte más directo. Además, ¿intentaste algo? Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo lo resolvi asi:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

InputStream excelStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file"));
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelStream);
Sheet sheet = hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = null;
Cell celda = null;
int rowIndex = 0;

rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIterator.hasNext();) {
    row = rowIterator.next();
    celda = row.getCell(celIndex);
    if (sheet.isColumnHidden(celda.getColumnIndex())) {
        // COLUMNA OCULTA
    } else {
        // COLUMNA VISIBLE
    }
}
```